# How to display specific data of an SQL table using php blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a program where an user is assigned to a project which has images and texts.

And obviously, in said program, an User can see the projects assigned to him and, by extension, the texts and images of the project.

But I have problem, where, if one user has 2 projects, when he looks for one project, he sees the data of both of them, as you can see in the next image:

[image: Example]

As you can see, it's showing both text 1 and 2 which are "Cambio 3" and "Cambio 1" respectively, but, it should only show the first text. The code I have for this is:

index_proyecto_blade.php

```php
<div class="row pt-4">
                    <h3>Textos</h3>

                    @foreach($usuario_proyecto as $usr_prt)

                    @foreach($proyecto_data as $prt)

                    @foreach($texto_data as $txt)

                    @foreach($texto_proyecto_data as $txt_prt)

                        @if($txt_prt->id_texto_data == $txt->id)

                        @if($txt_prt->id_proyecto_data == $prt->id_proyecto)

                        @if($usr_prt->id_proyecto == $prt->id_proyecto)

                            Id de texto: {{ $txt->id }}
                            <br>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <h5>{{ $txt->caption }}</h5>
                                <p>{{ $txt->texto }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        @endif
                        @endif
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div>
```

And here are the tables in play:

Usuario_Proyecto (relation between user and a project)

```
Usuario_Proyecto::all()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3061
     all: [
       App\Usuario_Proyecto {#3069
         id: 1,
         id_user: 2,
         id_proyecto: 1,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
       App\Usuario_Proyecto {#3062
         id: 2,
         id_user: 2,
         id_proyecto: 2,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Proyecto_data (clone of an original project)

```
Proyecto_Data::all()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3060
     all: [
       App\Proyecto_Data {#3063
         id: 1,
         nombre_proyecto: "["proyecto_test"]",
         id_proyecto: 1,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
       App\Proyecto_Data {#3058
         id: 2,
         nombre_proyecto: "["proyecto_test_2"]",
         id_proyecto: 2,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Texto_Data (clone of a text associated to a project/text associatod to Proyecto_Data)

```
texto_data::all()
[!] Aliasing 'texto_data' to 'App\texto_data' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3068
     all: [
       App\texto_data {#3069
         id: 1,
         nombre: "["this is a test caption"]",
         texto: "["Cambio 3"]",
         min: 1,
         max: 100,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
       App\texto_data {#3070
         id: 2,
         nombre: "["palaBRA2"]",
         texto: "cambio 1",
         min: 1,
         max: 100,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

Texto_Proyecto_Data (Relation between texto_data and proyecto_data)

```
texto_proyecto_data::all()
[!] Aliasing 'texto_proyecto_data' to 'App\texto_proyecto_data' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3071
     all: [
       App\texto_proyecto_data {#3050
         id: 1,
         id_texto_data: 1,
         id_proyecto_data: 1,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
       App\texto_proyecto_data {#3045
         id: 2,
         id_texto_data: 2,
         id_proyecto_data: 2,
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
       },
     ],
   }
```

The reason of why I use clones is because the user can edit their version of a project.

I make sure (I think at least) that the program only shows the data if the proyecto_id of text is the same the one in proyect and user. But it still shows the ones the text of other projects.

Why is that happening? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't want to fetch all the data and "filter" them in your view. 
Firstly, create proper relations between models.

Comment: @Hugo, can you share the controller?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating thing. Make your models simple and rely on relations between them. The reason why you're getting data from both projects is all these foreach loops. User has 2 projects, so you'll check conditions for both of them. Then you have unrelated texto_data, which is 2 objects. One of them includes conditions for one texto_proyecto_data and second one includes conditions for second texto_proyecto_data. Thats why you're getting both. Keep youre models and relations simple, do not overcomplicate things. Include only data you need in your view, not everything.

Comment: @Filip  Yeah, I did that.

Basically made another view for the users (both the normal user and admins where in the same view, despite them using different functions and versions of the projects (user has their cloned version, admin has the original))

And it worked !!! Thank you for the idea !!!

Answer (score -2):

the file name isn't right.

```
index.blade.php
```

In your controller, return view like `return view('proyecto.index');`; Basically `folder.file`

Always name the files `xxx.blade.php`

Hope it helped.